# Create ssh based remote path

Tags: git, ssh, libgit2

How should be set the url to add a `ssh` based `remote` path to an initialized repository? I have tried with

```
git_remote_create(&remote, repo, "origin", "ssh://git@github.com/libgit2/TestGitRepository");
```

but it does not `fetch` correctly and `git_remote_stats` returns 0 received objects. If `ssh` is replaced with `https`, `git_fetch` works as expected. <del>The same url works well with `git_clone`</del>(see comment):

```
git_clone(&repo, "ssh://git@github.com/libgit2/TestGitRepository", "foo", &clone_opts);
```

I have also tried to set `ssh://git@github.com:libgit2/TestGitRepository`, but it does not work either.

Comment: Are you checking for errors in `git_clone`?  Did you build with ssh support?

Comment: `git_clone` was returning err -4 (GIT_EEXISTS), which is given when the dest dir already exits. I wrongly assumed that `git_clone` was overwriting the dest dir (since `git_fetch` crashes in that case).  Apparently, I never fetched via ssh using `git_clone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused because I was not using the credential callback.

From the callback section in the libgit2 [documentation](https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/):

> For a credentials example, check out [the fetch example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/8720ae8a2c9045cb9494d328e3fc6370decbb774/examples/fetch.c#L78), which uses an [interactive credential callback](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/8720ae8a2c9045cb9494d328e3fc6370decbb774/examples/common.c#L179-L226). See also the built-in [credential helpers](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/transports/credential_helpers).

Below a minimal example to init+fetch+checkout a repo using ssh:

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <string.h>

int credentials_cb(git_credential **out, const char *url, const char *username_from_url,
    unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload)
{
  int err;
  char *username = NULL, *password = NULL, *privkey = NULL, *pubkey = NULL;
  username = strdup("git");
  password = strdup("PASSWORD");
  pubkey = strdup("/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub");
  privkey = strdup("/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa");

  err = git_credential_ssh_key_new(out, username, pubkey, privkey, password);

  free(username);
  free(password);
  free(privkey);
  free(pubkey);

  return err;
}

int main(void)
{

  git_repository *repo;

  git_libgit2_init();

  git_repository_init(&repo, "libgit2-test-ssh/", 0);

  git_remote *remote;
  git_remote_create(
      &remote, repo, "origin",
      "ssh://git@github.com/libgit2/TestGitRepository");

  git_fetch_options fetch_opts = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_INIT;
  fetch_opts.callbacks.credentials = credentials_cb;
  git_remote_fetch(remote, NULL, &fetch_opts, NULL);

  git_object *branch;
  git_revparse_single(&branch, repo, "remotes/origin/master");
  git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
  git_checkout_tree(repo, branch, &checkout_opts);

  git_object_free(branch);
  git_remote_free(remote);

  git_repository_free(repo);
  git_libgit2_shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if [`git_remote_create_with_opts`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/8720ae8a2c9045cb9494d328e3fc6370decbb774/include/git2/remote.h#L101-L116) would work better, as in [this test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/8720ae8a2c9045cb9494d328e3fc6370decbb774/tests/remote/create.c#L232-L242)

```
git_remote *remote;
git_strarray array;
git_remote_create_options opts = GIT_REMOTE_CREATE_OPTIONS_INIT;

opts.name = "test-new";
opts.repository = _repo;
opts.fetchspec = "+refs/*:refs/*";

cl_git_pass(git_remote_create_with_opts(&remote, TEST_URL, &opts));
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution using `git_remote_create_with_opts`. Nice to know how to fetch with more options.